# Game Center Turnbased Game turn timeout

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Has anyone used the turnTimeout parameter in `[endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:]`? What I would like is for player A to make a move and send the turn to player B. If player B does not respond within 48 hours, player A wins the game. This is one of the scenarios described by apple in their Game Center guide, but it doesn't really seem to be possible.

When I set the turnTimeout parameter, and player B doesn't make a move within that timeframe the turn automatically passes to player A (Who gets a GC notification banner saying it's their turn to make a move). player B doesn't get any notification at all. So even if I would try to internally end the game whenever the opponent times out, the user will still get this notification banner saying it's their turn to move (even though they already won the game).

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I'm facing the exact same issue.  It's bad UX for the player to receive a notification that it's their turn when the match is just to be automatically ended.